# how to determine the statistics of memory analyzer for android app

Tags: android, memory-leaks

i have just started to use `MAT` to analyse the memory and following is my attached report.

no i know to some extent how to use `MAT` but i don't what statistics stands for what reason. are my application's memory reports are good or worst ? how to determine it and resolve it to reduce the risk.

so how can i identify the critical area and steps to resolve those things

[image]

[image]